# Unwrapping a task either, handling errors, and providing default value

Tags: typescript, error-handling, task, either, fp-ts

Say I have some async function which fetches from an api and returns a taskEither (for simplicity, I'm providing a basic async task either:

```
const someAsyncFunction = taskEither.fromPredicate(
  (value: number) => value < 12,
  (value: number) => new Error("value was greater than 12")
)
```

I then want to report the error to sentry if it exists, however, I wish to inject a default value and continue downstream execution

```
const reportError = (error: Error) => console.log(error.message)

type ExceptionHandler = typeof reportError

const unwrapAndReportError = <R>(captureFunction: ExceptionHandler) => (
  def: R
) => (inputEither: taskEither.TaskEither<Error, R>): R =>
  E.getOrElse((err: Error) => {
    captureFunction(err)
    return def
  })(inputEither)

const runAsyncFunctionThenUnwrapAndReport = flow(
  someAsyncFunction,
  unwrapAndReportError(reportError)("potato")
)
```

This code fails to typecheck with:

```
Argument of type 'TaskEither<Error, R>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Either<Error, R>'
```

Fully runnable example: https://codesandbox.io/s/fp-ts-playground-forked-dy2xyz?file=/src/index.ts:0-722

My question is, how can this effect be achieved using fp-ts? What is the recommended pattern here (and how can I get it to typecheck).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're pretty close, `getOrElse` should work, although I think you're importing that from the `Either` module. Replace that with an import from the `TaskEither` module. Also, it's more idiomatic to use `pipe` so you can supply your task either argument first.

Perhaps something like this?

```js
import * as TE from "fp-ts/lib/TaskEither"
import * as T from "fp-ts/lib/Task"
import { pipe } from "fp-ts/lib/function"

const someAsyncFunction = TE.fromPredicate(
  (value: number) => value < 12,
  (value: number) => new Error("value was greater than 12")
)

const reportError = (error: Error) => console.log(error.message)

type ExceptionHandler = typeof reportError

const unwrapAndReportError = <R>(captureFunction: ExceptionHandler) => (
  def: R
) => (inputEither: TE.TaskEither<Error, R>): Promise<R> =>
  pipe(
    inputEither,
    TE.getOrElse(
      (error) => {
        captureFunction(error)
        return T.of(def)
      },
    ),
  )()

const runAsyncFunctionThenUnwrapAndReport = flow(
  someAsyncFunction,
  unwrapAndReportError(reportError)("potato")
)
```

Comment: I got this working using fold, but this solution actually seems more sensible, might rework mine later!

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately got this working with:

```
import { taskEither as TE, function as F, task as T } from 'fp-ts'

const unwrapEitherAndReport = <R>(captureFunction: ExceptionHandler) => (def: R) => (inputEither: TE.TaskEither<Error,R>): T.Task<R>=> F.pipe(
    inputEither,
    TE.fold(
        (err) => {
            captureFunction(err)
            return T.of(def)
        },
        T.of
    )
)
```

and running it with:

```
F.flow(
  someAsyncFunction,
  unwrapEitherAndReport(handler)('potato')
)
```